# Defining Auth strategy using Glue

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

I am using glue to spin up the hapi server so I gave the json object with connection and registration details.

I have 10 routes and i need to use authentication strategy for all the 10 routes, So followed the below steps

1) I have registered the xyz custom auth plugin

2) Defined the strategy `server.auth.strategy('xyz', 'xyz', { });`

3) At every route level I am enabling auth strategy

```
auth: {
     strategies: ['xyz'],
}
```

How can I give below line to glue configuration object itself.

```
server.auth.strategy('xyz', 'xyz', { });



Glue.compose(ServerConfig, { relativeTo: baseDir }, (err, server) => {
        internals.server = server;

})
```

One more question here is, in this line `server.auth.strategy('xyz', 'xyz', { from json file});` I am reading the JSON data from a config file. When I change the data in this JSON file I dont want to restart the server manually to load the modified data. Is there any plugin or custom code to achieve this?

Comment: You can use nodemon to automatically restart the server.

Comment: I echo the main questrion. How does the auth strategy setup integrate with Glue?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a general workaround for when you want to do setup that Glue does not directly support (AFAIK) and you also don't want to keep adding to index.js.

1. Create a `plugins` folder where your `manifest.js` is located.
2. Create a file `plugins/auth.js` (in this case). Here you will have a register callback with access to the server object and you can make setup calls that go beyond what Glue does declaratively.
3. Add a plugin item to `manifest.js` pointing to your plugin file.

in manifest.js:

```
register: {
  plugins: [
    {
      plugin: './plugins/auth',
    },
  ]
}
```

in plugins/auth.js:

```
module.exports = {
  name: 'auth',
  async register (server) {
    await server.register([
      require('@hapi/cookie'),
    ]);

    server.auth.strategy('session', 'cookie', {
      cookie: {
        name: 'sid-example',
        password: '!wsYhFA*C2U6nz=Bu^%A@^F#SF3&kSR6',
        isSecure: false
      },
      redirectTo: '/login',
      validateFunc: async (request, session) => {

        const account = await users.find(
          (user) => (user.id === session.id)
        );

        if (!account) {
          return { valid: false };
        }

        return { valid: true, credentials: account };
      }
    });

    server.auth.default('session');
  },
};
```

(auth setup code is from the Hapi docs at [enter link description here](https://hapi.dev/tutorials/auth/?lang=en_US#cookie))

This is the way I have found where I can call things like `server.auth.strategy()` sort-of from manifest.js.

Note: Auth is not a great example for this technique as there is a special folder for auth strategies in `lib/auth/strategies`.

Comment: Thanks Martin. 2 years later and this worked perfectly for me. Appreciate your help!